# What is a Tail Field and how to interpret it?

Tags: probability-theory

I cannot understand or form a good intuition in my head of what a tail field is. An introduction to rigorous probability theory by Rosenthal gives the following definition:

Given a sequence of events $A_1, A_2, ...$, we define their tail field:

$$\tau =  \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty\sigma(A_n, A_{n+1}, A_{n+2},\ldots) $$

So if an event A is an element of $\tau$, what does that mean in simple terms?

Comment: The way I think about it is that a tail event depends only on limiting, or 'large time' behaviour. For example, if $A$ is a convergent series of random variables, then $\lim_n A_n$ is a tail function. (If $A$ isn't convergent, then you could also consider, say, $\limsup_n A_n$, which is a tail function.)

Comment: Also, see this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/849457/interpretation-of-a-tail-event?rq=1.

Comment: After reading that question, I think I sort of get it...for any n, an event in the tail field only depends on the intersection of the n, n+1, n+2,...etc. sigma-algebras, right?

Comment: If I've understood you correctly, that's not quite right. A tail event can't depend on any specific $A_n$, for any $n$. Note that $A_n \notin \tau$ for any $n$, since you just take enough intersections and it's gone. "Tail" is really the right word for it, since it can only depend on "stuff at the end of the sequence".

Comment: With regards to real-world interpretation, or application, often these things are unclear when you first learn them. However, in my Part III essay, I'm showing that all bounded, harmonic functions on certain groups are in one-to-one correspondence with tail functions! This is just one of many uses, and you'll come across these as you do more maths. :)

Comment: Seems like good advice! :)

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this same confusion after reading the same text, and ended up at this question from a Google search. After reflecting a bit, I realize I got hung up on not knowing how to interpret the sub-expression $\sigma(A_n, A_{n+1}, A_{n+2},\ldots)$. Once I figured that out, the rest just fell into place for me.

So what does $\sigma(A_n, A_{n+1}, A_{n+2},\ldots)$ mean? It's just the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the collection $\{A_n, A_{n+1}, A_{n+2},\ldots\}$. It includes events like $A_i$, $A_j^C$, $A_k \cup A_l$, $A_k \cap A_l$, and so on, where $i, j, k, l \geq n$.

Now what about the $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty$ part? This just excludes events that only occur a finite number of times from influencing the generated $\sigma$-algebra. Say for example that $A_{32}$ never repeats. That is, there is no $k > 32$ with $A_k = A_{32}$. Then $A_{32}$ might not be part of the tail field. I say "*might*" here, because it could be part of the tail field. For example, if $A_{50} = A_{100} = A_{150} = \cdots$, and $A_{32} = A_{50}^C$, then $A_{32}$ will actually be in the generated $\sigma$-algebra. The important part though is that events that repeat infinitely often, like $A_{50}$, *will* influence the generated $\sigma$-algebra.

Answer (score 1):

**It's the set of all tail events**. Given infintely many random variables $X_i$, we call an $A \in \sigma(X_i, \, i \in I)$ a *tail event* if for all finite $I_0 \subset I$, we have $A \in \sigma(X_i, \, i \in I- I_0)$.

In other words, a tail event is an event that does not depend on finitely many of the random variables. It will occurr or not occurr regardless of what a finite subset of the random variables does. In German, we call it literally translated: "asymptotic events". That name is very suggestive.

And if you look at your defintion, it's the same idea. We take the intersection of all events that don't depend on the first $n$ random variables. And because the union is infinite over all $n$, we have the set of all events that don't care about finite subsets - it's those events that are "asymptotic".