# Interpretation of Tail Event

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I am trying to understand the interpretation of tail-events. The current answers existing on this matter helped me but did not convince me fully (in particular https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1414842/114720).

In fact, the answer cited above says that any event belonging in the tail field is independent of any finite number of events.

Contrary to the answer cited above, I would rather say that an event belong to the tail-field of $A_1$, $A_2$... is independent on any finite set of events$\in \{A_k\}_{k=1,.. ,n}$   *conditional* of the knowledge of $A_n$, $A_{n+1}$.. for any n.

The reason for this came from considering the algebra of a finite set $\Omega = \{1,2,3,4\}$. If we take $A_1 = 4$, $A_2 = \{1,2,3\}$, $X_1 = \sigma(\{4\})$ and $X_2 = \sigma(\{1,2,3\})$, $X_2$ contains by complementarity the event $A_1 = \{4\}$, so an element of $X_2$ is (trivially) dependent on $A_1$.

Am I right or I am missing something ?

Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, but you are making a real mess here of outcomes, events, $\sigma$-algebras and random variables. They should be properly discerned. Tail events always go along with a sequence of random variables $X_1,X_2,\dots$ and I cannot find any in your question.

Comment: You may be right but I am referring to Rosenthal book, "a first look at rigorous probability theory" which gives a definition of tail field in terms of events, and sigma algebras generated by sequence of events.